# Golang Package Import

Tags: go

I am attempting to get the following code to compile:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"    
    "code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(norm.IsNormalString("ŋ̊"))
}
```

I have installed the unicode/norm package. I compile with the command:

```
go build -o ipa ipa.go
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./ipa.go:9: undefined: norm.IsNormalString
make: *** [ipa] Error 2
```

It seems that the package is being imported correctly, but I cannot access any of its members. I have tried changing the method from being called to another from norm, but I still get the error. This leads me to believe that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about go's package system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> func (Form) IsNormalString
>
> ```
> func (f Form) IsNormalString(s string) bool
> ```
>
> IsNormalString returns true if s == f(s).

`IsNormalString` is not a function, it's a method on type `Form`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(norm.NFC.IsNormalString("ŋ̊"))
}
```

Output:

```
true
```